# AS3 Custom Object to ByteArray then to Custom Object

Tags: actionscript-3, object, arrays

Having problem reading bytearray of custom objects. Any help is appreciated

```
public class CustomObject extends Object {
public function CustomObject() {
public var _x:Number =  100
public var _y:Number = 10
public var _z:Number  = 60
}
}

var cObj:CustomObject = new CustomObject()
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray()
bytes.writeObject(cObj)
bytes.compress()

//read
try { bytes.uncompress() } catch (e:Error) { }
var obj:CustomObject = bytes.readObject() as CustomObject

trace(obj) // null why?!
trace(obj._z) // Obviously - TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to do is use the registerClassAlias method to register type information along with the data. That way Flash will know how to serialize/deserialize your object. Here's some sample code from Adobe's [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()):

```
registerClassAlias("com.example.eg", ExampleClass);
var eg1:ExampleClass = new ExampleClass();
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeObject(eg1);
ba.position = 0;
var eg2:* = ba.readObject();
trace(eg2 is ExampleClass); // true
```

It should be noted that *all* types that should be serialized must be registered for the type information to be saved. So if you have another type that is referenced by your type, it too must be registered.

Comment: woah register class, sounds expensive..does that cause any performance issues or what, ah i'll google it

Comment: Not really. It does store information about the type in the data, but it's not too inefficient. It doesn't really affect processing either all that much. It's used to store objects in the AMF protocol which is widely used for data transfer in the Flash platform. Other than manually storing type information and providing manual conversion from raw object data to specific types, this is your only option really and it's not bad.

Comment: yea I use 'custom' objects so that its faster than the new Object(); so wondered if it could cause performance issues in weird as3

Comment: Unless you have huge object graphs or serialize/deserialize huge amounts of object consistently, I wouldn't worry about it. In either case, adding typing information would probably be the least of your troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Your CustomObject class is wrong , it should throw an error actually , it should be this instead

```
public class CustomObject 
{
   public var _x:Number =  100
   public var _y:Number = 10
   public var _z:Number  = 60

   public function CustomObject() 
   {
   }
}
```

Edit:

Sounds like macke has a point, because this works...

```
//read
try { bytes.uncompress() } catch (e:Error) { }
var obj:Object = bytes.readObject();

trace(obj) // [object Object]
trace(obj._z) // 60
```

Comment: i dont think that would matter in this case does it?

Comment: i'm not sure actually , would need to test it... the CustomObject class is a bigger problem though!

Comment: awesome var obj:Object = bytes.readObject(); and registerClassAlias("com.example.eg", ExampleClass);
 does the trick

Comment: and about the CustomObject theres syntax error in the question, but in the actual class it is correctly coded..

Answer (score 0):

Look at object that `ByteArray.readObject()` returns. You'll probably see that all properties are there, but type information is lost. So, you can solve this by creating some

```
public static function fromObject(value:Object):CustomObject {
    var result:CustomObject = new CustomObject();
    result._x = value._x;
    //and so on...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the problem is custom object have another custom object in it...for example cObj._myHome = myHome, where myHome:MyHome extends object

Answer (score 0):

To serialize custom classes to the `ByteArray`, you must put `registerClassAlias` in the constructor of the class calling the `byteArray.writeObject()` function.

If you don't, your custom class will be serialized as Object type. I was calling `registerClassAlias` in the serialize function below and my custom class keeps getting serialized as `Object` until I moved the `registerClassAlias` to the constructor.

```
public class MyClass{
    public function MyClass(){
        registerClassAlias("com.myclass", MyClass); // Ok, serializes as MyClass
        serialize( new MyClass() );
    }

    private function serialize( _c:MyClass ){
        var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        byteArray.writeObject( _c );
        //registerClassAlias("com.myclass", MyClass); Not ok, serialized as Object
        EncryptedLocalStorage.setItem('key', byteArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: the call to registerClassAlias must come before the call to ByteArray:writeObject, but it **does not** have to be in the constructor of the class to be serialized.